# Subjunctive vs. present tense

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, subjunctives

> I suggest the new leadership be needed.

I learned subjunctive mood recently and now I know you could parse this as such, *"I suggest the new leadership **should** be needed."* However, now I got confused all the more for the present tense like this one below.

> [image]
>
> I suggest the new leadership is needed.

It's like, to me, the whole sentence should have subjunctive mood according to the situation in which the speaker is. But still, it's just in the normal and present tense... how? What could be the differences between the sentences each above?

Comment: "I suggest new leadership is needed" is not subjunctive. It's ***a passive form***. And both should be needed and be needed are a mistake here. Also, I would suggest removing the "the". "Subjunctive" would be: I suggest ***he leave*** now. This is only relevant in the third person singular, present tense.

Comment: You clearly haven't noticed that the *original* form doesn't have a definite article (you've erroneously transcribed it as ***the** new leadership*). If you're still at the stage of not noticing ***significant*** details like that (and presumably not being aware of the difference it makes), you definitely shouldn't be wasting time trying to understand subjunctive usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  apparently some people feel differently, as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) gives *"She suggests that he speak English"* as an example of the subjunctive, although it's not clear why.

Comment: @Andrew: That's got nothing to do with my point, which is that ***the*** significantly affects the meaning. So OP's example could only be "grammatically" understood as referring to ***a specific new leadership** (already contextually identified)*. In which case it would be syntactically identical if we changed ***the new leadership*** to any other "specific" identifier, such as a proper noun. But "subjunctive" *I think John be needed* is clearly ungrammatical/nonsensical with or without ***should***, outside of non-standard dialectal contexts. And it's no different with OP's example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Er ... my mistake?  I addressed the comment to the wrong person.  It *should have been directed* at Lambie's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called subjunctive (which is identical to the base form for every verb in the language, so I don't understand why some grammarians insist on giving it a different name) is used by *some* people after verbs like *insist*, *decide*, *suggest*, *command*, but not by everybody.

It is used more in formal contexts (like committee meetings), and I think more by American than British speakers.

As you say, forms with "should" are a common alternative. But the simple present is also used, especially in British English.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *to suggest* can take a subjunctive object, but it also can take an indicative object.   The difference can be meaningful.

> I suggest that something is true. 
>   I suggest that something be done.

In the indicative case, we are quite naturally describing things as they are.  Here, the something is true -- whether I make the suggestion or not.   No one needs to follow my suggestion in order to make that thing be true.   In the subjunctive case, we are describing things as they are *not*.   The something *isn't* done -- not yet, not until someone follows the suggestion.   At the very least, I don't assume that this something is already done when I make such a suggestion, even if I happen to be mistaken.

> ? I suggest that new leadership be needed.

This just seems strange.   Am I suggesting that someone should *create* the need, or that we can't know whether new leadership is needed?

The subjunctive doesn't make sense here.   She's not presenting a hypothetical or contra-factual idea in this clause.   Assuming that the *if*-clause is true (and, in this context, we should), she's describing her world as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether or not this sentence would actually be *subjunctive*, as there seem to be different opinions.  However I can say that using "should" in combination with requests, opinions, or commands, *reduces* its intensity.  This can be deliberate way to make the request more *formal* and *polite*, but possibly also a bit old-fashioned:

> I ask that you (should) call me by my first name.

I'm not British, so I defer to Colin Fine's nationality, but to me this sounds more like something a posh British person would say, but few Americans.  Over here in the U.S. it would be far more common to say:

> Please call me by my first name.

In a different context (such as a committee meeting) "should" is a relatively benign added layer of politeness.  It's not necessary, but it might sound nice and avoid "ruffling feathers".  Example:

> I motion that we (should) vote on this immediately.