# I suggested that she [buy / bought] a car?

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, subjunctives

From p. 68 of [English Grammar in Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Grammar_in_Use) 5th edition:

> Jane won the lottery.
> *I suggested that she buy a car.*
> *I suggested that she bought a car.*

Do the two sentences mean the same?
If not, what's the difference?

The following is a related question, but I think it doesn't answer my question directly: [Difference between present and past simple after 'suggested that'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196357/difference-between-present-and-past-simple-after-suggested-that)

Answer (score 1):

Jane won the lottery.
(a) I suggested that she **buy** a car with the prize money.
(b) I suggested that she **should buy** a car.
(c) I suggested **buying** a car.
(d) I suggested that she **bought** a car.

All of the above are acceptable forms in English. Although a careful American speaker–unfamiliar with British English–might find (d) awkward and view it as incorrect.

The verb "suggested" is in the past, so the suggestion was made at a specific point in time.  In (a), (b) and (c) the winner of the lottery may or may not have decided to purchase a car. Buying a car was an idea, something for her to consider, but we don't know what happened after that.

Without further context, (d) is ambiguous.

> (d) I suggested that she **bought** a car.

This could mean that the winner of the lottery did in fact buy a car after the idea had been put forward. It was *my* idea for her to buy it.
OR
The winner did not buy a car; she ignored the suggestion and spent the money she'd won on something else.

For reference see the website [English Grammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/suggest/)

> When the verb in the main clause is in the present tense, we can use a
> present tense in the that-clause after suggest. When the verb in the
> main clause is in the past tense, a past tense is possible in the
> that-clause as well.
>
> - His doctor **suggests** that he **stops** smoking.
> - His doctor **suggested** that he **stopped** smoking.
>
> In American English, **subjunctive** structures are
> more common after *suggest*. Note that a subjunctive has the same form
> in the present tense and the past tense. It doesn’t have the –s
> marking in third person singular.
>
> - The doctor **suggests** that he **stop** smoking. (Subjunctive with no –s
>   marking.)
> - The doctor **suggested** that he **stop** smoking.
>
> In British English, subjunctive isn’t very common. Instead, British speakers use **should + infinitive**.
>
> - The doctor **suggests** that he **should stop** smoking.
> - The doctor **suggested** that he **should stop** smoking.
>
> In direct suggestions that begin with I **suggest**…, **should** is not
> normally used.
>
> - I **suggest** that you **get** another job. (NOT I suggest that you should get another job.)

Alternatively, the following is also acceptable

- I **suggested** that you **got** another job.

Using the past tense of "got" here appears to be more common in BrEng, implying (perhaps) that the person did the thing suggested. However, without context this is, at best, a supposition.

From the [BBC site](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv201.shtml) (which is British) we have the following examples of past form of the verbs in the ***that-clause***

- I *insisted / demanded that* he **stopped** phoning me.
- Everybody *recommended that* she **continued** with her education for 3 more years.
- It *was desirable (that)* she **went** to a school where Italian was taught.

---

Comment: Thanks @Mari-Lou A, this is very helpful! I interpreted the difference between (a) and (d) as the following: Whereas (a) only mentions the fact I suggested it to her, (d) means I suggested it to her *and some action has already been taken by her*.  (maybe including doing nothing?) Is it Correct?

Comment: @Akira we don't know for certain whether the lottery winner did or didn't spend her money. We only know that the suggestion was made some point in the past.

Comment: Do you mean that's for both (a) and (d)? If it's so, they virtually have the same meaning?

Comment: It's possible that the car was purchased, I thought I'd explained it in my answer. Language doesn't always make logical sense. It just is. Many speakers would consider (d) using the simple past tense to be incorrect but people *do* say it.

Comment: Surprise! I get a downvote. I suppose that's called tit for tat.

Comment: This: (d) I suggested that she bought a car. differs from the others in one way: The speaker is talking about the woman to another person. I suggested [to some group of people) that you got another job.

Answer (score 1):

Jane won the lottery.
I suggested that she buy a car.
I suggested that she bought a car.

**The first means I suggested this to her**. [This implies suggested to her.]

WHEREAS, the second means:

**I suggested [to individuals not present] that at some point she bought a car**.

That is the difference in meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence means she has not bought a car yet and you are suggesting to her to buy one.

The second sentence means you suggested to buy a car and she already bought one.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because it is misleading. See the following source for a correct answer:  https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv201.shtml

Comment: Um what does the link mean, I did not really see anything relevant in the link, mostly about "should" @RonaldSole

Comment: It's AmEng vs BrEng. You could look up the  subjunctive in the archives.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/222598/1694 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/187361/1694

Comment: Thanks for great comments, guys! I've read the all link pages you provided, but I couldn't be sure, so can you confirm the following my thought? (1) @DialFrost 's answer is correct, but only applies to American English. (2) In British English, both sentences mean exactly the same. Am I right?

Comment: Your "you suggested her" may be considered by some as non-standard English. This a very common mistake among learners, I hear it all the time "I suggest you visit a museum” instead of "I suggest that you visit a museum” or “I suggest visiting..."

Comment: Suggested her to buy is not grammatical in English.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, edited